# ¿Qué estilo hace que mi href no este funcionando?

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo en mi navbar un anchor tag que dice translate y deberia ir a `englis.html` pero no funciona y no se si tal vez los estilos esten tapando este anchor tag...

```js
const navbarToggler = document.querySelector(".toggle__button");
const navbarMenu = document.querySelector(".navbar ul");
const navbarLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar a");

navbarToggler.addEventListener("click", navbarTogglerClick);

function navbarTogglerClick() {
  navbarToggler.classList.toggle("open-navbar-toggler");
  navbarMenu.classList.toggle("open");
}

for (let i = 0; i < navbarLinks.length; i++) {
  navbarLinks[i].addEventListener("click", navbarLinkClick);
}

function navbarLinkClick(event) {
  smoothScroll(event); // Call the "smoothScroll" function

  if (navbarMenu.classList.contains("open")) {
    // Close navbarMenu in smaller screens
    navbarToggler.click();
  }
}

function smoothScroll(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const targetId =
    event.currentTarget.getAttribute("href") === "#"
      ? "header"
      : event.currentTarget.getAttribute("href");
  const targetPosition = document.querySelector(targetId).offsetTop;
  const startPosition = window.pageYOffset;
  const distance = targetPosition - startPosition;
  const duration = 1000;
  let start = null;

  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);

  function step(timestamp) {
    if (!start) start = timestamp;
    const progress = timestamp - start;
    // window.scrollTo(0, distance*(progress/duration) + startPosition);
    window.scrollTo(
      0,
      easeInOutCubic(progress, startPosition, distance, duration)
    );
    if (progress < duration) window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }
}

// Easing Functions

function linear(t, b, c, d) {
  return (c * t) / d + b;
}

function easeInOutQuad(t, b, c, d) {
  t /= d / 2;
  if (t < 1) return (c / 2) * t * t + b;
  t--;
  return (-c / 2) * (t * (t - 2) - 1) + b;
}

function easeInOutCubic(t, b, c, d) {
  t /= d / 2;
  if (t < 1) return (c / 2) * t * t * t + b;
  t -= 2;
  return (c / 2) * (t * t * t + 2) + b;
}
```

```css
/*----------------- NAVBAR ------------------*/
.navbar {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  height: 7.5rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--grey-light-2);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  color: var(--grey-dark-2);
  box-shadow: 0 -1rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: "Lato Bold";
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.toggle__checkbox {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 56.25em) /* 900px */ {
  .navbar-list {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: stretch;
  }

  .navbar-list > * {
    padding: 0 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all 0.5s;
  }

  .separator {
    display: block;
    width: 0.2rem;
    height: 4.5rem;
    background: var(--grey-light-2);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 -0.2rem;
  }

  .navbar__item:hover:not(:last-child) {
    background-color: var(--grey-light-2);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
  }

  .navbar__link:link,
  .navbar__link:visited {
    color: var(--grey-dark-2);
    text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
  }

  .navbar__item:not(:last-child) .navbar__link i {
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
  }

  #big-icon {
    font-size: 4rem;
    z-index: 20;
  }

  .navbar__link i {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  .navbar__item:last-child {
    position: relative;
  }

  .navbar__item:last-child:hover::before {
    content: "";
    width: 6rem;
    height: 6rem;
    background-color: var(--grey-light-2);
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 10;
  }

  .toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  .notification {
    font-size: 1rem;
    height: 2rem;
    width: 2rem;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: var(--color-red);
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: -0.5rem;
    right: -0.5rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 30;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-list">
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a class="navbar__link" href="#sobre-mi">
          <i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>Sobre mi
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a class="navbar__link" href="#habilidades">
          <i class="fas fa-th"></i>Habilidades
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a class="navbar__link" href="english.html">
          <i class="fas fa-globe-americas"></i>Translation 
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a class="navbar__link" href="#proyectos">
          <i class="fas fa-archive"></i>Portafolio
        </a>
      </li>
      <div class="separator">&nbsp;</div>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a class="navbar__link" href="#certificados">
          <i class="fas fa-award" id="big-icon"></i>
          <span class="notification">7</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: si esta al mismo nivel de index.html de hecho seria la version en ingles del index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redacto mejor la respuesta. Lo que ocurre es que en el javascript estás usando un preventDefault en las etiquetas de los links. Eso evita que se ejecute el comportamiento por defecto, el cual es el que tratas de utilizar.

Comment: si era eso pero ahora me aparece el # en la url, ¿alguna sugerencia? y gracias :)

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], ayudaría mucho exponer a mayor detalle el por que de tu solución, ya que así aunque es la solución parece solo un comentario y no deja claro el por que

Comment: Quitale el # en el <a class="navbar__link" href="#certificados">

Comment: if(targetId === "#") event.preventDefaul(); pero ¿el # acaso no se usa con los id?, en los otros si uso ids

Comment: Ya me fije. Si usas el # para las otras cosas. Pero el caso del English.html no quieres hacer scroll, sino saltar a otra ventana. Por lo que es seguro remover el #

Answer (score 0):

El problema no es el estilo, eso depende en que nivel se encuentre tu página "englis.html" si esta al mismo nivel de la página que carga este código

```
mypagina.com/default.htm
mypagina.com/english.htm
```

debería funcionar sin problema usando :

```
<a class="navbar__link" href="english.html">.
```

Si se encuentra afuera en un nivel anterior:

```
mypagina.com/paginas/default.htm
mypagina.com/english.htm
```

usa

```
<a class="navbar__link" href="../english.html">.
```

Comment: <a class="navbar__link" href="../english.html"> hice esto y no me funciona tenia esto <a class="navbar__link" href="english.html"> pero tampoco funciona, probe cambiar los z-index de los estilos pero tampoco

Comment: mmm debería funcionar sin problema, ¿sería posible copartieras la url de tu página y la de english.html ? @CeciResponde

Comment: todavia no esta subida la estoy abriendo con live server XD, pero igual probe una url cualquiera por ejemplo la de github y no me la abre